# css shift overflow to top-left

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I want to display content - other divs containing text - in a div on my website.

The div is a child of a flexbox.

Sometimes, this content is bigger than the size of my div.

But this is not a problem, as I only want the stuff at the bottom-right corner of the content to be visible anyway.

What I do is use the property `overflow: hidden;`. But this lets the content overflow to the right and bottom instead of the left and top.

---

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

---

I tried:

- using `overflow: scroll;` and scrolling to the maximum, but this broke my layout.
- using `direction: rtl;`, but this reverses the direction of my text instead of the overflow.
- using `float: right;`, which doesn't do anything.

---

Do you have any suggestions for what I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need the CSS and HTML code to give you a precise answer, but I think that you can solve the issue by giving:

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

to the parent and:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right:0;
```

to the child element.

Comment: Perfectly works! I have to check whether the content is overflowing, because it should be aligned normally otherwise.